# C#: What's the difference between the params keyword and giving a default value

Tags: c#, keyword, params-keyword

The title pretty much says it all, but what I would like to know is whether there is an advantage to using one or the other?

For example:

```
public void MyMethod(params string[] list) { }

public void MyMethod(string[] list = new string[] { }) { }
```

How are those different?

Comment: The first one allows you to call the method with multiple string parameters while the second one requires exactly one array of strings.  So `MyMethod("one", "two", "three")` vs `MyMethod(new [] { "one", "two", "three" })`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.